# how can i use database connection of the already connected database in codeigniter?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-3

I have already database connected in config folder `database.php` file.
Is there any variable that can simply refers to that `MySQLi` connection, so that i can use the connection and do manual insertion like-

```
mysqli_query($alreadyconn, "insert into table ...");
```

[`insert()` in Codeigniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#insert)

I know how to insert in codeigniter but i need the above specific case. and here i can not reconnect that database and use the variable.

Any Help Much Appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Seems you know about `database.php`. Will get know some more

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost', # host
    'username' => '', # Username
    'password' => '', # password
    'database' => '', # Databse name
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli', # this can be MySQL or MySQLi
```

> **Note:** Recommend to use MySQLi as db driver.

---

### How to connect database??

There are Three ways to archive this

1. Gobally - (path - `application/config/autoload.php`)

   ```
   $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
   ```
2. Within the class only.

   ```
   class ClassName extends CI_Model 
   {
       public function  __construct()
       {
           parent::__construct();
           $this->load->database();
       } 
   }
   ```

   > Can use in all the methods added within this class
3. Withing Methods only. (Mostly on controllers only)

   ```
   class ClassName extends CI_Controller {

       public function  __construct()
       {
           parent::__construct();
       }

       public function index()
       {
           $this->load->database();
       }
   ```

   > Can use inside the class only

---

### What is Query Builder (3.0+) or Active Records(3.0-) ??

This pattern allows information to be retrieved, inserted, and updated in your database with minimal scripting. In some cases only one or two lines of code are necessary to perform a database action. CodeIgniter does not require that each database table be its own class file. It instead provides a more simplified interface.

---

### How to query with the database & (Query Builder or Active Records) ??

First Load DB in `autoload.php` mention above(personally recommended).
Where ever you are in model or controller just use `$this->db` to get open connection with your DB.
With that you can add **Query Builder methods** like mention in the [codeigniter docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html). if you are like to use **traditional SQL method**, you feel free to use `query()` (Which is my favorite).

**Example**

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = 'Sparatn' AND ... OR... ");
```

But this not enough to produce meaningful data. So you have to follow these steps as well

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = 'Sparatn' "); # 1
$result  = $query->result_array(); # 2
return $result; #3
```

> In **#1** assign the database row data to an variable.
>   In **#2** Convert the #1 to objective array(`result_array` objective array represent by this).
>   In **#3** return the result to controller.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$this->db` to refer to your db connection

```
$query = $this->db->query("
        YOUR QUERY HERE
");
```

Answer (score 1):

To Insert Data In Database you must do not need MySQL function in code igniter . 
You should have to use

```
     $this->db->insert()
```

function to store data in database . 
For More Help kindly visit
https://www.formget.com/insert-data-into-database-using-codeigniter/
Thank You

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I know i can use $this->db->insert() to insert into database. But i wanted to insert using MySQL function. Can't i use MySQL function directly in Code Igniter ?

Comment: Yes you are able to use mysqli function

Comment: But not in view or controller

Answer (score 1):

None really answered to the question. The question is clear: how to recycle the **codeigniter database connection** to be used with a native `mysqli_query` function without using `mysqli_connect` again.
The upvoted answers above aren't helpful by any means to the issuer's question.

Use `$this->db->conn_id` as database connection reference in your `$alreadyconn` variable.